# An issue occurred while installing a starter template in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wpforms

I was trying to install a WordPress starter template and it showed an error.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD9i5.png) is the error message I got:

> ## We are building your website...
>
> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> > **What went wrong?**
> >
> > Importing forms failed due to parse JSON error.
> >
> > **More technical information from console:**
> >
> > ```
> > There was an error downloading the WP Forms file
> > ```
>
> <kbd>Click here and we'll try again →</kbd>

I searched about this error on Google & YouTube, but I didn't get anything useful.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the Astra template.

First, you should try to manually install WP Forms plugin. The retry the demo import.

If that doesn't work, you may want to check that your server PHP settings are optimal to allow you to import the demo. Optimal PHP settings should look like this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 48M
memory_limit = 256M
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_vars = 1000
max_input_time = 400
```

The amounts can vary depending on your server. You may also want to check with them to be sure.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried both of them still now working, do you have any other solution?